# gif not getting loaded in .exe file written in pytho

Tags: python, exe

I have written a python script where gif is playing completely fine when I run it through the terminal but after I create the .exe file, the gif is not getting loaded. Can someone please tell me what the issue here is
The code is here:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QMovie
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class LoadingGif(object):

    def mainUI(self, FrontWindow):
        FrontWindow.setObjectName("FTwindow")
        FrontWindow.resize(320, 300)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(FrontWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("main-widget")

        # Label Create
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(25, 25, 200, 200))
        self.label.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(250, 250))
        self.label.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(250, 250))
        self.label.setObjectName("lb1")
        FrontWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        # Loading the GIF
        self.movie = QMovie("loader.gif")
        self.label.setMovie(self.movie)

        self.startAnimation()

    # Start Animation

    def startAnimation(self):
        self.movie.start()

    # Stop Animation(According to need)
    def stopAnimation(self):
        self.movie.stop()


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
demo = LoadingGif()
demo.mainUI(window)
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

To create the .exe file I am using the following command:

```
pyinstaller --onefile abc.py
```

Please note the .exe file runs but the gif is not visible.

Comment: If it works without the `--onefile` parameter then it has something to do with not being able to find the path to `loader.gif` after its bundled to a temporary folder.

Comment: gif is not getting loaded even if the parameter --onefile is removed sir

Comment: Can you share your folder structure? and where you are running `pyinstaller`?

Comment: I am running pyinstaller from the same folder in which this python script is located. Is there any way I can add the path of my gif file while running the command <pyinstaller abc.py>

Comment: Did you copied your exe file out of the dist folder so that it is in the same place as the loader.gif? Or try the absolute path for loading the file, like C:\Users\user\videos\loader.gif